# Linker error while building statically-linked wxHaskell application

Tags: haskell, gcc, linker, ld, wxhaskell

I am trying to statically link a wxHaskell Windows application using this `ghc -static -optl-static` flag. But ld.exe returns a linker error

> c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxc
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I seemingly can't find lwxc in my system anywhere. Is there anything that I can do?

Edit:
I have libwxc.a in

> E:\wxhaskell\wxc\libwxc.a

Comment: Can you find `libwxc.so` (or dll)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the linker is telling you is that it can't find the library because it is not in the standard location that it knows...
Add it to GHC's library search path by adding the `-L` flag to the command:

```
ghc -static .... -LE:/wxhaskell/wxc ....
```